# How to run angular 6 html page any other html / any language site?

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I have created the Angular 6 project with 3 dropdown and textarea input.
I have made Html page in textarea on the selected dropdown. now I have made textarea HTML page to use other websites.
How, Any one help?

Comment: Please add your code, you have written so far for achieving this, and explain a little more about what you want to do with that code. Thanks.

Comment: Example: I have one dropdown in angular 6 and it is working fine below code
we have used in a .ts file
countries = [
     new Country(1, 'USA' ),
     new Country(2, 'India' ),
     new Country(3, 'Australia' ),
     new Country(4, 'Brazil')
  ];
bind in .html like as 
      <select>
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries" value= {{country.id}}>
    {{country.name}}
  </option>
</select>

Now  I have created one HTML project.html file and fill up above the dropdown in it. I want to use angular 6 in project.html file.
How to possible on one HTML file to use angular 4/5/6.

Comment: So you want to bind `project.html` with your .ts file to use angular in your html, right ?

Comment: no , It is not possible to use .ts file in html page, so I am using only html with <script> tages